# What is meant by the term 'unbounded compounding'?

Tags: option-pricing, compounding

I am currently trying to make sense of a paper by Mark Braverman and Kanika Pasricha titled "The computational hardness of pricing compound options".

On page 3 of this paper, it claims that

> *"With unbounded compounding, the problem of (risk-neutral) pricing compound options is PSPACE-hard, even in the presence of full information, where the distribution of the future world-states is just uniform, and the function mapping future states to payoffs is a poly-time computable function. Specifically, options considered are compound European put options."*

My question is, what do they mean by 'unbounded compounding'? Does this this just mean that we assume that the market risk-free rate is compounded *continuously*?

Comment: A compound option is for example a Put on a Put. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_option I have not read your paper, but I assume unbounded compounding could be for example :a put on a put on a put on a put, with as many levels as you want.

Comment: That would make a lot of sense.